Help understanding Spivak's solution, and a verification of my proof. Spivak Chapter 5, Question 3(vi)

Find a $\delta$ such that if $0<|x-1|<\delta$  then $|\sqrt{x}-1|\lt
 \epsilon$

My solution:
$|\sqrt{x}-1|\cdot |\sqrt{x}+1|=|x-1|$
$
\epsilon>|\sqrt{x}-1|\ge |\sqrt{x}|-1$ which implies $\epsilon+1>|\sqrt{x}|$ . This directly implies that $\epsilon+2>|\sqrt{x}+1|$. Thus $\delta=\epsilon(\epsilon+2)$ Q.E.D
Spivak's Solution:

If $\epsilon>1$, let $\delta=1$. Then
$|x-1|<\delta$ implies that $0<x<2$, so $0<\sqrt{x}<2$, so
$|\sqrt{x}-1|<1$. If $\epsilon<1$,then
$(1-\epsilon)^2<x<(1+\epsilon)^2$ implies that
$|\sqrt{x}-1|<\epsilon$, so it suffices to choose $\delta$ so that
$(1-\epsilon)^2\le 1-\delta$ and $1+\delta\le (1+\epsilon)^2$. Thus we
can choose $\delta=2\epsilon-\epsilon^2$

I have been trying for quite a while to understand the logic behind this proof. The derivation of $\delta$ makes me quite confused. More specifically the convention $(1-\epsilon)^2\le 1-\delta$ and $1+\delta\le (1+\epsilon)^2$. Because if we write $(1-\epsilon)^2\ge 1-\delta$ and $1+\delta\ge (1+\epsilon)^2$ then we have
$$ 1+\delta\ge (1+\epsilon)^2>x>(1-\epsilon)^2\ge 1-\delta$$ This implies $|x-1|<\delta$
. It is also a mystery to me how delta is derived(i.e when $\delta=2\epsilon-\epsilon^2$) . Because if we adopt the convention above we have $1+\delta\ge (1+\epsilon)^2$ and $(1-\epsilon)^2\ge 1-\delta$, so $\delta\ge\epsilon^2+2\epsilon$, $-\delta\le\epsilon^2-2\epsilon$,so $\delta\ge\epsilon^2+2\epsilon$ and $\delta\ge-\epsilon^2+2\epsilon$ adding these two together we arrive at $2\delta\ge4\epsilon$ and finally $\delta\ge2\epsilon$ So we can let $\delta=2\epsilon$ Q.E.D
As you can see, I'm quite lost, any help would be appreciated thanks!

Please verify your QED. Scratch work is all fine and good,  but you must do the (forward) algebra to prove your $\delta$ actually works.

OP's analysis is fine, but he makes a small mistake. On the one hand we have $1-\epsilon < \sqrt x < 1 + \epsilon$, which after squaring leads to $(1-\epsilon)^{2} < x < (1+\epsilon)^{2}$. On the other hand we have the relation $1-\delta < x < 1+\delta$. We must determine a $\delta$, such that when the second relation holds, also the first relation holds. Therefore:
$$(1-\epsilon)^{2}< 1-\delta < x < 1 + \delta < (1 + \epsilon)^2 $$
Hence we derive two relations: $\delta < 2\epsilon - \epsilon^{2}$ and $\delta < 2\epsilon + \epsilon^{2}$. To be certain both relations are satisfied, we must choose the more restrictive first relation. Hence $\delta = 2\epsilon - \epsilon^{2}$ is the correct answer, as was obtained by Spivak. It is in fact the largest value for $\delta$, such that the relation in terms of $\epsilon$ holds. But of course smaller values for $\delta$ are also possible.
